# Arduino nano Serial port not recognized

Tags: arduino-nano

First sorry for my bad english, not my native lenguage.

Today I started working on my Arduino nano (first time used). When plugged for the first time the "L" led started blinking, after that I tried to write a simple program but I noticed that the "Port" option on the Arduino IDE was Gray. So I couldn't choose the port. After that I searched A LOT but nothing seems to work.

While trying to test if the problem was the Arduino and not the PC, I make a simple circuit with 1 LED, 1 resistor of 1Kohm, and a breadboard. I connected the 5V pin to the LED and GNG to the other point, And when I did this the "L" LED stopped blinking forever. I am 100%  sure that I did not make a short circuit. ¿Maybe the breadboard is in a bad state?

Additional info:

-Windows 10.
-The port doesn't appear at Device manager (tried every port of my notebook).
-The "POW" led is ON when I plug the USB.
- The Arduino is a clone (chip CH340G).

So now I don't know if the problem is the port or if the Arduino Nano is dead because of a possible short circuit between 5V and GND pins.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install the CH340G drivers?

Comment: I can't because the COM doesn't appear on Device Manager.

Comment: Not even in Unknown Devices ?

Comment: No. It doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Sounds like you most likely killed it. Maybe show how you wired the LED up with a photograph of it on your breadboard.

Comment: I can't show a picture, but I'm 100% that the connection was OK because that was my first fear so I watched closely and the 5V pin wasn't in the same line that the GND pin.

Comment: Maybe then it's just the curse of the cheap Chinese clone.

Comment: I assume you have tried another USB port and another cable, and tried something else in the USB port you had the Arduino in?

Comment: Yes, I tried all that.

Comment: And the results were that the board didn't wake up no matter which cable and port you tried, and the something else worked fine in the port you had been using?

Comment: Yes, I have an Arduino Uno and that works fine. When I plug the Nano The "POW" LED turns ON but nothing more.

Comment: Sounds like it may be fried. Possible that the CH340G has died.

Comment: Yes I think the same. Thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 1):

I think your Arduino got short or the transmitter-receiver in it is damaged so the device manager cannot recognize the COM port.It once happened with my Arduino Uno. Try changing the USB cable.If it does not help your Arduino is damaged.